# "Move" list column to site columns in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint

One of the users in a SharePoint installation created a few columns as list columns, these columns are now needed on site level so we must "lift" or "move" them somehow. I figured this could be related to the SourceId property but are unaware of the rest.

Any advice is appreciated, thanks

Comment: What tools are available to you?  Visual Studio, SharePoint Designer, or just the built-in features in the SharePoint web interface?

Comment: This is a on premises installation so I have VS, SPD, PowerShell and so on. We do have both farm admin and local admin rights.

Answer (score 1):

From my own research on this topic, it looks like you should save the site as a template and then import the template into Visual Studio.

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/30045/importing-custom-list-to-visual-studio-from-sharepoint

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/14805/export-a-list-from-sharepoint-2010-into-visual-studio-2010

If the site is too large to save as a site template, then save the list as a list template.  For the list template, you'll get a `*.stp` file, which is nothing more than a Microsoft cabinet file - so change the extension to `*.cab` and you can extract the `manifest.xml` file from the cab.  Inside `manifest.xml` you'll find the definitions for the list's columns.

[Import list template STP file to Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093140/import-list-template-stp-file-to-visual-studio-2010)

Inside the manifest.xsf file, extracted from the *.cab (which was renamed from *.stp), you can find field definitions like this:

```xml
<ListTemplate WebUrl="http://host/sites/site">
<Details> ... </Details>
<Files> ... </Files>
<UserLists>
    <List Name="{guid}" ...>
        <MetaData>
            <Views> ... </Views>
            <Fields>
                <Field Type="Text" Name="MyField1" DisplayName="My Field 1" ID="{guid-1}" ... > ... </Field>
                <Field Type="Note" Name="MyField2" DisplayName="My Field 2" ID="{guid-2" ... > ... </Field>
                <Field Type="Status" Name="MyField3" DisplayName="My Field 3" ID="{guid-3}" ... > ... </Field>
                <Field Type="URL" Name="MyField4" DisplayName="My Field 4" ID="{guid-4}" ... > ... </Field>
            </Fields>
            <ContentTypes> ... </ContentTypes>
            <Forms> ... </Forms>
            ...
        </MetaData>
    </List>
</UserLists>
</ListTemplate>
```

Within a Visual Studio SharePoint project, the list field definitions can be copied and pasted from their source files into a SharePoint site column "elements.xml" file.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">  
  <Field
       ID="{abd3b925-1e2c-4423-8e9b-7a861be38917}"
       Name="SiteColumn1"
       DisplayName="Site Column 1"
       Type="Text"
       Required="FALSE"
       Group="Custom Site Columns">
  </Field>
</Elements>
```

Just replace the default `Field` element from Visual Studio's `Site Column` template with a field definition from the list.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">  
    <Field Type="Text" Name="MyField1" DisplayName="My Field 1" ID="{guid-1}" ... > ... </Field>
</Elements>
```

Once all the fields you want to move are in your project as individual Site Columns, compile and deploy the project to place the site columns into your site.

Comment: Cool, in my scenario this would most likely be possible.

Comment: Hi.. This worked like a charm for me as well. But I am facing a different situation now. My list columns already has values and after adding all of them as site column also the list column is not changing to site column. I have to add those columns to the content type used in the list manually. Do you know how do I achieve this using powershell or visual studio. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user705831 I am no SharePoint expert, but I understand that whenever SharePoint uses a site column within a list or library, the site column's definition is **copied** into the list's own definition.  From this point forward, the list columns have a separate definition from the original site column.  I know that SharePoint has some mechanisms for propogating changes to the source definitions into the copied definitions, but I don't recall if that applies with site columns to list columns or only from list templates into actual lists.